# UIWebView Swift изменить цвет ссылок

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Есть ли способ изменить цвет ссылок в `UIWebView` с синего на произвольные?

HTML получаю с сервера и править его не могу, устанавливаю в `UIWebView` при помощи

```
loadHTMLString(string,url)
```

попытка изменить `tintColor` не спасла

```
webView.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Уйти от `UIWebView` не могу, тк в разметке может быть видео

Есть ли еще какие то способы изменить цвет ссылок в `UIWebView`?

Comment: мне чисто для себя, а почему видео не позволяет уйти от webView?

Comment: другие классы, такие как uilabel или uitextview которые позволяют поместить в себя attributedtext не показывают видео (как я понял нужна поддержжка js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не скажу насколько правильный вариант, но относительно рабочий (для моих целей достаточно, может и Вам подойдет):

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let scriptLinksColor = "$(document).ready(function () {$('a').css('color', 'red');});"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(scriptLinksColor)
}
```

Результат на примере Вашего вопроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Не забудьте о `UIWebViewDelegate` в IB или коде.

Comment: странно, delegate указан, но тем не менее не получается, все равно ссылки синие. Пытался и в didFinishLoading и в  webViewDidStartLoad

Comment: сработало аналогичное решение, только не  с jquery, a c js